# Adding space to the top and bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a `HTML`document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell:700,400' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:700,400' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link type="text/css" href="./mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content">
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</P>
            <div id="nextPage" class="next">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

which is being styled by this CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 550px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    margin: 20px 60px 40px 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.page-title h1 {
    height: 55px;
    font-family: "Play";
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.page-content {
    font-family: "Cantarell";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.next {
    font: 23px "Play";
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 605px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Is there a way using cross-browser compatible `CSS` to add some blank space to both the top and the bottom of the `<div>` of class `next`? At the moment, it doesn't matter how much I give to its `margin-bottom` property, the gap between the 'Next' link and the last time of `Blah Blah Blah` does not change, and the there is very little space between the link and the bottom of the page.

Comment: To separate it from last Blahblah you have to use `margin-top`

Comment: @Nelson, for some reason, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are what work for me. Neither `margin-top` nor `margin-bottom` does anything in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use padding-top, and padding-bottom to create the white space.

For example:

```
.next {
    font: 23px "Play";
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 605px;
    padding-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```

Will add 300 pixels on top and underneath the "next" link.

Answer (score 0):

Try....

```
.next {
    font: 23px "Play";
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 605px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

The clear both property may or may not create issues with other content, but it works fine based on what you've posted.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/hJXGB/1/)